# Subconsulta con extración del año de un campo datetime

Tags: sql

Buenas ocupo hacer este ejercicio de Subconsultas que me permita mostrar información de los empleados que fueron contratados en el mismo año que 'nancy' lo intente con el like, tambien igualando, con el DATEDIFF y aun no soluciono, el campo hiredate es de valor datetime

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.LastName, E.FirstName, E.Title, E.TitleOfCourtesy, E.BirthDate, E.HireDate
FROM Employees E
WHERE E.HireDate =(
SELECT E.HireDate
FROM Employees E 
WHERE E.HireDate like 1992 
)
```

Comment: Para renombrar una columna, necesitas poner AS. FROM employees AS E

Comment: Lo que hace falta es que lo intentes, creo yo.  ¿que has intentado y que errores te ha dado?  Si lo intentas podremos ayudarte mejor, sino pues va a ser que nos pasas la tarea/ejercicio a nosotros y aqui no hacemos tareas (o no deberiamos)

Comment: @CarlosAgut No es necesario usarlo siempre, puede ser omitido.

Comment: Ah, de acuerdo!

Comment: @masterguru intente de varia maneras lo intente igualando el HireDate a la fecha que ocupo sin embargo no me aparece nada, ni erro

Comment: Perfecto, pues agrégalo a la pregunta para que sea mejor recibida y se note que lo has investigado, que es lo primero que se pide en las directrices de [ask] de este sitio. Puedes modificar la pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en gris en el pie de la pregunta las veces que sea necesario. Agrega el intento y el error (o la falta del mismo) para que podamos aconsejarte mejor y saber lo que has hecho y que te has olvidado de hacer durante tu intento real.

Comment: Vale, necesitamos saber que tipo de campo es el campo **HireDate** y un ejemplo de alguno de los valores almacenados. Por cierto, cuando hagas un LIKE intenta encerrarlo entre `%` y además comillas (simples o dobles, da igual, lo que te vaya mejor y no de errores en el resto de tu código), es decir, `LIKE "%1992%'`

Comment: Luego veo que pones los nombres de columnas distintos: `E.HireDatE` y `E.HireDate`. No se si puede afectar eso a tu consulta, pero intenta ponerlos **exactamente** como los tengas definidos en la estructura de tu tabla

Comment: @masterguru utilice el like con comillas y sin comillas y si comillas no me salta error, sin embargo con las comillas si, me dice que retorna mas de un valor

Comment: ¿Que base de datos utilizas? Mysql, Sqlserver?

Comment: @JuanGarcia Prueba mi respuesta a ver que te sale ahora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.LastName, E.FirstName, E.Title, E.TitleOfCourtesy, E.BirthDate, E.HireDate
FROM Employees E
WHERE YEAR(E.HireDate) =(
SELECT YEAR(E.HireDate)
FROM Employees E 
WHERE E.FirstName = 'nancy'
)
```

### Explicación

La clave está en lo que se está buscando, el año, y al ser una columna del tipo datetime se puede usar la función [YEAR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) para extraerlo facilmente. Y en la subconsulta lo que necesitamos saber es el año de **nancy** por lo tanto lo ponemos en el **WHERE**.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono, justo estaba probando con el DATEDIFF(YEAR ETC) y aun no me funcionaba, muchas gracias

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya funcionado :-)  Saludos!

Comment: gracias, igualmente feliz dia

Answer (score 1):

La lógica que debes tener es la siguiente:
un select que traiga los datos que quieres mostrar, en el `where` vas a comparar la fecha de contratación, para sacar la fecha de nancy debes hacer un select anidado en tu `where` en donde le digas que te regrese la fecha en donde su campo nombre sea el de nancy,  cuando pones `'% texto %'` lo que hará sql es tomar el texto y compararlo, da igual que en el registro se llame "Nancy" , "nancy" , "NanCy", "nancy fernanda" mientras incluya la palabra nancy te regresará un registro, tienes que tener cuidado cuando uses el like, por que puedes tener mas de un registro que contenga el texto que quieres comparar, pero ese es otro tema, para ello lee sobre "Like SQL"

es la parte del `where`:

```
... Where E.HireDatE = (Select HireDatE from Employees where FisrtName like '%nancy%')
```